# How can I pass variable to ansible playbook in the command line?

Tags: variables, command-line, command-line-arguments, ansible

How can one pass variable to ansible playbook in the command line?
The following command didn't work:

```bash
$ ansible-playbook -i '10.0.0.1,' yada-yada.yml --tags 'loaddata' django_fixtures="tile_colors"
```

Where `django_fixtures` is my variable.

Answer (score 384, accepted):

Reading the docs I find the section [Passing Variables On The Command Line](https://web.archive.org/web/20141020060716/http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line), that gives this example:

```bash
ansible-playbook release.yml --extra-vars "version=1.23.45 other_variable=foo"
```

Others examples demonstrate how to load from *JSON* string (≥`1.2`) or file (≥`1.3`)

Comment: Note also that variable(s) defined with `--extra-vars` will override the variable(s) defined inside playbook.

Comment: Also note (from the docs): Values passed in using the `key=value` syntax are **interpreted as strings**. Use the JSON format if you need to pass in anything that shouldn’t be a string (Booleans, integers, floats, lists etc). For example: `--extra-vars '{"i_wasted_30_mins_debugging_a_boolean_string":true}'`

Comment: Since key values are interpreted as strings, in my script I use the following technique to convert to integer: {{ myVar | int }}

Comment: another handy way to pass vars by cli, is to use an input file, for example 
`ansible-playbook release.yml --extra-vars "@my-file.yml"`

Comment: but how to define it in yml file? this should not be the selected answer. below one is.

Answer (score 202):

Other answers state how to pass in the command line variables but not how to access them, so if you do:

```
--extra-vars "version=1.23.45 other_variable=foo"
```

In your yml file you assign these to scoped ansible variables by doing something like:

```
vars:
    my_version: "{{ version }}"
    my_other_variable: {{ other_variable }}
```

An alternative to using command line args is to utilise environmental variables that are already defined within your session, you can reference these within your ansible yml files like this:

```
vars:
    my_version: "{{ lookup('env', 'version') }}"
    my_other_variable: {{ lookup('env', 'other_variable') }}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about?? My answer *expands* on previously accepted answers by referring to the command line flag --extra-vars *AND* how to reference them within your yaml configuration. Then I offer an alternative way of doing it as well.

Comment: The question here is specifically pass variable **through command line**. That's exactly why it would be better as it's own question/answer and a related link. You can and the related link as a comment to the question.

Comment: The expanded answer helped me. Surely knowing how to reference the variables passed in part of knowing how to pass parameters. Otherwise your not passing them but rather just declaring you want to pass the variable. To pass an object requires a giver and receiver. To pass a variable requires a parameter declaration and a usage of the parameter.

Comment: `lookup('env', SOMETHING)` is matched the 12 factor.

Comment: Remember to change the variable's name: `version: {{ version }}` is wrong, like defining `version` by itself.

Answer (score 48):

```
ansible-playbook release.yml -e "version=1.23.45 other_variable=foo"
```

Comment: The `-e` flag is the short form of `--extra-vars`

Comment: Can I pass variable file?

Comment: @AniruddhaJawanjal yes, like `--extra-vars "@some_file.json"`

Comment: @OpsEco @AlanSE note that if you are passing variables from a file, you need a second `--extra-vars` flag to pass variables not in the file.  For example `--extra-vars "@some_file.json" --extra-vars "other_variable=foo"`

Comment: Does the file have to be json formatted? or can it be in yaml format?

Answer (score 40):

For some reason none of the above Answers worked for me. As I need to pass several extra vars to my playbook in Ansbile 2.2.0, this is how I got it working (note the -e option before each var):

```
ansible-playbook site.yaml -i hostinv -e firstvar=false -e second_var=value2
```

Comment: `-e` is the short form of `--extra-vars`

Comment: You can also define multiple variables using a single flag: `-e "firstvar=false second_var=value2"`

Comment: Same problem.  Multiple vars with a single flag would not work.  I wonder why?

Answer (score 35):

You can use the `--extra-vars` option.  [See the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime)

Answer (score 16):

```
ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-vars "arg1=${var1} arg2=${var2}"
```

In the yml file you can use them like this

```
---
arg1: "{{ var1 }}"
arg2: "{{ var2 }}"
```

Also, `--extra-vars` and `-e` are the same, you can use one of them.

Answer (score 9):

```
 s3_sync:
      bucket: ansible-harshika
      file_root: "{{ pathoftsfiles  }}"
      validate_certs: false 
      mode: push
      key_prefix: "{{ folder }}"
```

here the variables are being used named as 'pathoftsfiles' and 'folder'. Now the value to this variable can be given by the below command

```
sudo ansible-playbook multiadd.yml --extra-vars "pathoftsfiles=/opt/lampp/htdocs/video/uploads/tsfiles/$2 folder=nitesh"
```

Note: Don't use the inverted commas while passing the values to the variable in the shell command

Answer (score 7):

This also worked for me if you want to use shell environment variables:

`ansible-playbook -i "localhost," ldap.yaml --extra-vars="LDAP_HOST={{ lookup('env', 'LDAP_HOST') }} clustername=mycluster env=dev LDAP_USERNAME={{ lookup('env', 'LDAP_USERNAME') }} LDAP_PASSWORD={{ lookup('env', 'LDAP_PASSWORD') }}"`

Answer (score 7):

In Ansible, we can define variables when running our playbook by passing variables at the command line using the `--extra-vars` (or `-e`) argument.

**Bellow are some ways to pass variables to an Ansible playbook in the command line:**

### Method 1: key=value format

```
ansible-playbook site.yml --extra-vars "arg1=demo1 arg2=demo2"
```

### Method 2: JSON string format

```
ansible-playbook site.yml --extra-vars '{"arg1":"demo1","arg2":"demo2"}'
```

**The `site.yml` playbook will be:**

```
---

- name: ansible playbook to print external variables
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: print values
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "variable1 = {{ arg1 }}, variable2 = {{ arg2 }}"
    when: arg1 is defined and arg2 is defined
```

### Method 3: Read from an external JSON file

If you have a lot of special characters, use a JSON or YAML file containing the variable definitions.

```
ansible-playbook site.yml --extra-vars "@vars.json"
```

**The `vars.json` file:**

```
{
   arg1: "demo1",
   arg2: "demo2"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`ansible-playbok -i <inventory> <playbook-name> -e "proc_name=sshd"`

You can use the above command in below playbooks.

```
---
- name: Service Status
gather_facts: False
tasks:
- name: Check Service Status (Linux)
shell: pgrep "{{ proc_name }}"
register: service_status
ignore_errors: yes
debug: var=service_status.rc`
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ansible-playbook release.yml --extra-vars "username=hello password=bye"

#you can now use the above command anywhere in the playbook as an example below:
tasks:
- name: Create a new user in Linux
shell: useradd -m -p {{username}} {{password}}"
```